# pyTelegrambotApi how to add photo?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I am doing telegram bot using pyTelegramapiBot (Python). It works on the principle of a sequence of questions and shows general information. I want to add the ability to upload photos.
Logic: The user enters a name, surname, his photo. And he is shown general information with a photo.
Question: How to get a user's photo exactly at the moment when it is required? Otherwise, nothing will happen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def addImage(message):
    if not message.photo:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Add image")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, addImage)
        return
    item = data[message.from_user.id]
    item.photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=item.photo])
```